autoconf error in trying to build TPM2.0 simulator on M1 Mac
I'm trying to build a TPM2.0 simulator on macOS Sonoma (14.2.1) using Official TPM 2.0 Reference Implementation (by Microsoft) and it seems to be failing at generating a make file for executing. This is what I get when I execute the following steps:
 $ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig"

 $ ./bootstrap
 Generating file lists: src.mk
 Setting up build
 Setting default vendor strings

 $ PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig" EXTRA_CFLAGS=-fno-common ./configure
 checking for gcc... gcc
 checking whether the C compiler works... yes
 checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
 checking for suffix of executables... 
 checking whether we are cross compiling... no
 checking for suffix of object files... o
 checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
 checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
 checking for gcc option to enable C11 features... none needed
 checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
 checking whether ln -s works... yes
 checking for ranlib... ranlib
 checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
 checking whether build environment is sane... yes
 checking for a race-free mkdir -p... mkdir -p
 checking for gawk... no
 checking for mawk... no
 checking for nawk... no
 checking for awk... awk
 checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
 checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
 checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
 checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
 checking for libcrypto... yes
 ./configure: line 4650: syntax error near unexpected token `,'
 ./configure: line 4650: `AX_PTHREAD(, AC_MSG_ERROR([requires pthread]))'

So when I try to do a make it ends up with a make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. I think this could be because ./configure does not finish successfully. I tried to check for autoconf and autoconf-archive and both are installed:
 $ brew info autoconf
 ==> autoconf: stable 2.72 (bottled)
 Automatic configure script builder
 https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf
 Installed
 /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf/2.72 (71 files, 3.6MB) *
  Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-05-05 at 23:35:38
  From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew- 
  core/blob/HEAD/Formula/a/autoconf.rb
  License: GPL-3.0-or-later and (GPL-3.0-or-later with Autoconf-exception-3.0)
  ==> Dependencies
  Required: m4 ✔
  ==> Analytics
  install: 80,276 (30 days), 271,841 (90 days), 651,247 (365 days)
  install-on-request: 15,529 (30 days), 53,376 (90 days), 147,214 (365 days)
  build-error: 67 (30 days)

 $ brew info autoconf-archive
 ==> autoconf-archive: stable 2023.02.20 (bottled)
 Collection of over 500 reusable autoconf macros
 https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/autoconf-archive/
 Conflicts with:
  gnome-common (because both install ax_check_enable_debug.m4 and ax_code_coverage.m4)
 Installed
 /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf-archive/2023.02.20 (600 files, 3.6MB) *
 Poured from bottle using the formulae.brew.sh API on 2024-05-06 at 12:08:19
 From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/a/autoconf-archive.rb
 License: GPL-3.0-or-later
 ==> Dependencies
 Required: autoconf ✔
 ==> Analytics
 install: 489 (30 days), 1,581 (90 days), 6,361 (365 days)
 install-on-request: 371 (30 days), 1,048 (90 days), 4,227 (365 days)
 build-error: 0 (30 days)

I wanted to check if there are some configurations or PATH I might be missing to link autoconf to fix the error.

The upstream configure.ac and flags.m4 files lacks the proper m4_pattern_forbid lines for the non-autoconf and non-automake m4 macros like PKG_* and AX_*. Those will then throw errors in the case of missing macro definitions at the time when the error actually happens, i.e. during autoreconf/bootstrap instead of producing an invalid configure script. I have no idea why your homebrew autoreconf finds a definition for the PKG_CHECK_MODULES macro but not for AX_PTHREAD.
